# Service layer getting complex and unmaintainable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

In my application, I have a service layer, which is many REST web services that deal with the DAO layer to do CRUD operations on the entities which represent database tables. I am using Hibernate in my DAO layer. An example of my Service layer Java classes was:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService extends SessionUtil implements Service {

public static CustomerDao customerDao = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("customerDAO");
public static CustomerDebtDao customerDebtDao = (CustomerDebtDao) context.getBean("customerDebtDAO");

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer> getAllCustomersService() {
    return (ArrayList<Customer>) customerDao.getAllCustomers();
}
@GET
@Path("/{start}/{end}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer> getCustomerBatchService(@PathParam("start") int start, @PathParam("end") int end) {
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = (ArrayList<Customer>) customerDao.getCustomerBatch(start, end);
        return customers;
}

@GET
@Path("/count")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int getTotalRowCountService() {
    return (int) customerDao.getTotalRowCount();
}

@GET
@Path("/{customerId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Customer getCustomerService(@PathParam("customerId") int customerId) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customerDao.getCustomer(customerId);
    return customer;
}
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createCustomerService(Customer customer) {
    customerDao.createCustomer(customer);
    return response;
}

@DELETE
@Path("/{customerId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deleteCustomerService(@PathParam("customerId") int customerId) {
    customerDao.deleteCustomer(customerId);
    return response;
}

@PUT
@Path("/{customerId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response editCustomerService(Customer customer) {
    customerDao.editCustomer(customer);
    return response;
}
...
}
```

An example of the DAO layer is:

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CustomerDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    customer.setCustomerId(getNextCustomerId());
    customer.setCreated(new Date());
    customer.setCustomerId(getNextCustomerId());
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(customer);
    try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void editCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(customer);
    try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, in the service layer, I sometimes make more than one call to the DAO layer, and as you see, each call is handled in one Hibernate transaction which causes that if one operation fails, the others won't be executed. For example, I am telling the code to create an invoice then update the debts of the customer. I could find that it created an invoice and did not update debts. I looked into a couple of books and they all said I should handle all operations in a single transaction and roll them back if anything fails. I am trying to do this, but it's causing me to almost remove the whole DAO layer, and the service layer is getting huge, unreadable and unmaintainable. An example is as follows:

```
@POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createSalesInvoiceLineService(SalesInvoiceLine salesInvoiceLine) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    // prepare sales invoice line object
    salesInvoiceLine = salesInvoiceLineDao.createSalesInvoiceLine(salesInvoiceLine);
    session.save(salesInvoiceLine);

    updateSalesInvoiceAmountForCreate(salesInvoiceLine, session);
    // update stock
    Stock stock = stockDao.getStockByProduct(salesInvoiceLine.getProductId());
    stock.setQuantity(stock.getQuantity().subtract(salesInvoiceLine.getQuantity()));
    stockDao.editStock(stock);
    session.save(stock);
    // update debt
    SalesInvoice salesInvoice = salesInvoiceDao.getSalesInvoice(salesInvoiceLine.getSalesInvoiceId(), session);
    List<CustomerDebt> customerDebtList = customerDebtDao.getCustomerDebtByCustomerId(salesInvoice.getCustomerId());
    CustomerDebt customerDebt = customerDebtList.get(0);
    customerDebt.setAmount(customerDebt.getAmount().add(salesInvoiceLine.getLineAmount()));
    Date date = new Date();
    java.sql.Date currentDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    customerDebt.setUpdateDate(currentDate);
    customerDebtDao.editCustomerDebt(customerDebt);
    session.update(customerDebt);
    try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Please post this on codereview as it is working code and just requires optimization

Comment: You missed everything that Spring is useful for: dependency injection, and automatic, declarative transaction management. You should really read the Spring documentation. All you should need for a transactional service is the `@Transactional` annotation. All you should need to get a DAO instance is `@Autowired` on your service constructor, or on its non-static fields. You also missed the fact that Hibernate entities are managed. Calling save() on an entity you got from the session is useless. And BTW, save() is for creating a new persistent instance.

Comment: Casting the lists you get from the DAOs to ArrayList is also completely useless, and could actually make your code fail, for nothing.

Comment: In addition to using container managed transactions (@Transactional) you probably also want to take a look at spring-data, it has JpaRepository which does all the mindless save, find, count and even pagination. Also I often end up creating a static factory method on Entities, so I can hide the setDate() and other methods that need to be invoked after object construction. Also getNextCustomerId() looks like a strange method, it is rare to see an Entity ID which is not managed by JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to existing comments:
add pure service layer where you implement business logic using DAOs and use that layer via dependency injection in REST layer e.g.

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService  {
    private Service service; 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomersService() {
        return (ArrayList<Customer>) service.getAllCustomers();
    }
...
```

service layer can be easily tested, exposed to other transport layers(SOAP,..)...

Comment: Alright, thank you guys for the comments. I will try doing all of this.